# Designing an SMPS circuit on eagle (finding the right transformer and parts) 230VAC to 5VDC

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, rectifier, bias

I'm very new to the world of electrical design. I'm trying to create a SMPS circuit on eagle and am struggling to find the right transformer. I'm currently following this circuit (page 7):
https://www.power.com/sites/default/files/PDFFiles/rdr158.pdf

[image]

I'm having trouble finding a transformer like this. The one listed in parts is the have bias windings on opposite side (might be a stupid question). Does this not matter as they are used for control? Also is there anything I should watch out for in terms of the specific capacitors, diodes, and resistors I pick. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ICE-Components/TP07161/?qs=%2fha2pyFaduiT1uU%252bGDh6ygX8DHe9R5WeEEtE4DxxWZwNkl42%2fDqS1w%3d%3d&utm_source=octopart&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_campaign=911-TP07161&utm_content=ICE%20Components

Answer (score 1):

The BOM and DIY design details are provided for you.

- T1 Custom Transformer, EE16, 10pins;

  - per Power Integrations' [RD-158 Transformer Specification](http://www.eeworld.com.cn/zt/PowerIntegrations/pdf/rdr158.pdf)
  - Santronics SNXR1346
  - Ice Components TP07161
  - Precision, Inc  019-6120-00

[image]

Comment: Yea sorry I forgot to mention that but I was just curious to why the bias windings are in other side does this not matter as they are for control? Sorry if it's a stupid question

Comment: Secondary insulation is specified for 3kV, that's why layout order is as it is.. Primary windings are not... I would design it for 6kV if I lived anywhere with exposed power lines above ground to place of use, which might be 1 extra layer of tape if rated for 3kV between WD4 and WD5

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble finding a transformer like this

Try [Premier Magnetics](http://www.premiermag.com/html/product-family/power-magnetics.html): -

[image]

They do most of the link switch product range. See the link halfway down the page for the device you want to use.

> The one listed in parts is the have bias windings on opposite side
>   (might be a stupid question).

Naive rather than stupid!

> Also is there anything I should watch out for in terms of the specific
>   capacitors, diodes, and resistors I pick

The circuit you linked has a very clear BoM so follow that and if something isn't clear get back and ask specifics. In other words look at the BoM: -

[image]